# Update Query Script Needs Mentoring

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'stock' with columns serial_no, identifier, floated_on, current_owner and update_at.  I am trying to create an update query for updating the current_owner which is a foreign key from table named users. The update_array has three variables named $present_owner, $share_count and $ new_owner.  The script that I have written is as shown below.  However, it doesn't seem to update the database upon execution.  Help will be appreciated

```
$db->query("UPDATE stock (SELECT * FROM stock
    WHERE owner_id = ? LIMIT = ?)
    SET owner_id = ?", array($present_owner, $share_count, $new_owner));
```

Comment: Some sample data and the expected result after updating would be helpful here.

Comment: What kind of object is `$db`?

Comment: Also, `LIMIT` makes no sense here without also using `ORDER BY`.  _Which_ records within the limit do you want to update?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I don't know if i am doing the right way but I am trying to limit the number of shares for which the ownership will be transferred to the new owner.

Comment: OK, but you need to tell us what the `ORDER BY` clause would be here.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thanks for being there.  The column floated_on is a datetime and ORDER BY should be according to the oldest.